# Add information to an existing legend in an Octave plot

Tags: plot, octave, legend

I have a figure in Ocatve 4.4.1, with a single plotted dataset and its corresponding legend.

I want to add another plot to that figure (in the same primary XY axes, but I doubt this is relevant here), and extend the legend with this plot.

I managed to accomplish the first (adding the second plot), using

```
fig = figure(1) ;
hold on ;
plot(...) ;
```

with the same figure as before.
But I could not extend the legend.

I guess one way of doing this is getting the text of the legend, and setting it again extending the text with what I want.
That may lose some formatting, but it would be ok for a starter.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [answer provided by Cris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582066/2707864) I put together a simple and versatile solution.

I had the style used for plotting (e.g., `'-r'`) as a string named `style`.
Then, as shown in [official documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html#Two_002dDimensional-Plots), I could choose via a variable `leg_param` whether to extend the legend for each added plot, with

```
if ( !strcmp(leg_param, '') )
    style = [ style ";" leg_param ";" ] ;
endif    
ploth = plot(xtab1, ytab1, style) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the legend text in the plot command:

```
plot(...,'DisplayName','legend text here')
```

The legend should update automatically. If it doesn't, you can turn it off and then back on again (isn't that always the solution to computer problems?):

```
legend off
legend show
```